# Table in PHP needs to be aligned

Tags: php, text, row

I have this PHP script which turns out like this [image]

```
echo "<center>";
                            echo "<table dir='ltr' text-align: center>"; 
                           echo "<tr>";
                     
                        echo "<td><b>".    '<span style="color: #C4FB57;" /> Nickname: </span>' . $row['nume'] . ' <span width= "200" style="color: #3DFCE5;" /> Logged at: </span>'. $row['date'] .'<span style="color: #E7FA2F;" /> Status: </span>'.$row['ip'].     "</td></b>"; "</td></b>"; 
                                                       
                    echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                    } 
                echo "</center>";
```

and I want it to be aligned, to doesn't matter the $row, i want "nickname", "logged at" and "status" to be aligned under each other no matter what the result from db would be.

Thank you!

Comment: You're putting all your text in a single table cell. Break it up so the different items each have their own cell.

Answer (score 0):

Break up the row so that the different elements each appear in their own cell:

```
<?php
$rows = [['nume'=>'Some Name','date'=>'Some Date','ip'=>'Succeeded'],
        ['nume'=>'Some Other Name','date'=>'Some New Date','ip'=>'Failed']
    ]
;
echo "<center>";
echo "<table dir='ltr' style='text-align: left'>";
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";

        echo '<td><span style="color: #C4FB57;" > Nickname: </span>' . $row['nume'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><span style="color: #3DFCE5;" > Logged at: </span>' . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><span style="color: #E7FA2F;" > Status: </span>' . $row['ip'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

echo "</center>";
```

Output:

[image]

You might want to think about those colours!

Answer (score -1):

Try below,

```
<?php
    
    $row['name'] = "test name";
    $row['date'] = "test date";
    $row['ip'] = "test ip";
    
    echo "<table dir='ltr' style='text-align:left'>"; 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td style="text-align:left">
                <b><span style="color: #C4FB57;"/> Nickname: </span>
                ' . $row['name'] . '</b>
          </td>'; 
    
    echo '<td style="text-align:left">
                <span width="200" style="color: #3DFCE5;"> 
                Logged at: </span> '. $row['date'] .'</span></b>
          </td>'; 
                
    echo '<td style="text-align:left">             
                <span style="color: #E7FA2F;"> 
                Status: </span> '.$row['ip'].'</td></b>';
      
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: This still has all the elements in a single cell. The alignment will vary as data from the database varies.